# SQLiteTransactionListener onCommit and onRollback never called

Tags: android

I am trying to use the SQLiteTransactionListener to know when a batch transaction has committed so I can send an notifyChange event to observers in a ContentProvider.

The code starts a transaction for the bulk operation, and has nested transactions for each insert or update.

I receive the onBegin message for each startTransaction of the bulk operation, however I never receive the onCommit or onRollback

I have logged out the begin and end transaction calls to confirm that the nested calls are completing for each transaction, and as can be seen below, these are always matching.

```
Finish batch operation: success = true
End batch transaction
Begin batch transaction
Bulk transaction: onBegin
Inserting values into "Messages"table
insert values transaction begin
insert values transaction success
notifyChange not sent due to currently processing batch operation
insert values transaction end
Inserting values into "Content"table
insert values transaction begin
insert values transaction success
notifyChange not sent due to currently processing batch operation
insert values transaction end
Update values transaction begin
Update values transaction success
notifyChange not sent due to currently processing batch operation
Update values transaction end
Finish batch operation: success = true
End batch transaction
Download begining for content ID 12
```

I have also looked at the code for SQLiteDatabase [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java), but could see no reason this function would not be called. I have tried to find some examples of this online (here and in google search) but only find API documentation.

Has anyone had some success using this class? Or can someone please tell me why I would not be getting this event?

Comment: After some further investigation I have found these callbacks do work, but only when you do not have nested transactions. For nested transactions I do not get a onCommit or onRollback call.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code of SQLiteDatabase.java, the nested transaction call beginTransaction() will clear or replace the SQLiteTransactionListener set by the parent transaction. Every time call beginTransaction(), mTransactionListener will be changed.

```
private void beginTransaction(SQLiteTransactionListener transactionListener,
        boolean exclusive) {

        mTransactionListener = transactionListener;

}
```